# How to fetch specific columns from nested relationships - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables as follows

**Course Table**

```
ID | title     | 
---|-----------|
1  |  course 1 |
```

**Chapter Sections Table**

```
ID | course_id | title             |
---|-----------|-------------------|
1  |       1   | Chapter Section 1 |
2  |       1   | Chapter Section 2 |
```

**Chapters Table**

```
ID | chapter_section_id | title     |
---|--------------------|-----------|
1  |       1            | Chapter 1 |
2  |       2            | Chapter 2 |
```

I have defined the relationship as follows.

**COURSE Model**

```
public function chapterSections() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CHAPTER_SECTION', 'course_id');
}
```

**CHAPTER_SECTION Model**

```
public function chapterSections() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CHAPTER_SECTION', 'course_id');
}
```

Now I just want to fetch title column from chapters table. Referring to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)This is my attempt.

```
COURSE::with('chapterSections.chapters:id,title')->get();
```

I am getting columns from courses table as well as chapter_sections table but instead of receiving columns from chapter tables I get empty array.

**My postman output**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "course 1",
        "chapter_sections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "course_id": 1,
                "title": "Chapter Section 1",
                "chapters": []
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "course_id": 1,
                "title": "Chapter Section 2",
                "chapters": []
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want is to fetch just id and title column chapters table. This is my desired output.

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "chapter_section_title": "chapter section 1",
            "title": "chapter 1",
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "chapter_section_title": "chapter section 2",
            "title": "chapter 2",
        }
    ]
```

Is there any relationship way of doing it or I have to use joins to get the above output

Comment: i recommend using hasMnayThrow:  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through and loading it

Comment: `hasManyThrough` works for the situation. but now I realize that `title` from `chapter_sections` table is also required. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can have your chapters inside your section chapter by also using a with on the section chapter, same way as you did it on course.

If you want to have them with all the response then you declare the $with on your section chapter.

If you want to have them only for this response then you use the static method exactly like you did it with the course.

Good luck